# Umbraco 7: Random 404

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have never experienced this issue in Umbraco 4, but we've got this twice in Umbraco 7.

**The Problem**

So we've got a page: www.mywebsite.com/sale

It has been working for a month, then suddenly it shows 404:

[image]

**The** (non-ideal) **Solution**

We could change the template of this document, eg. from SalePage to TextPage, then back to SalePage.
That will temporarily fix it.

But after IIS restart, or after republishing the page, it will show the 404 error again.

For a permanent fix, we have to change the page name, eg. from Sale to Sale1.

**The Question**

Sometimes changing the page name is not an ideal solution at all.

Has anyone experienced this? Or know where to look? May be the database has a corrupted entry somewhere..?

Comment: Which version are you working on?  Consider asking this question also on the umbraco forum (http://our.umbraco.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem! We have this structure under Content:

- Home

  - HomeSlide1
  - HomeSlide2
- Pages

  - Sale
  - About Us
  - etc

The problem started when someone created a "home slide" under **Home** called "**sale**".

So, both Home/sale and Pages/Sale has the same path: **/sale/**

Deleting/renaming Home/sale fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a corrupt cache.

To find out what went wrong: 
Investigate the xml config (/config/umbraco.config)?  I suspect this file will still contain the correct information.

If the umbraco.config file doesn't contain wrong elements, check the examine indexes.  When you do a "rebuild indexes" from the developer node in the umbraco backend the problem might go away also.

If you know what is going wrong, you can start finding a solution for fixing the issue. E.g. finding out which action went wrong.